# Axios Can't access Heroku app - Error : Network Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, heroku, axios

I'm using Express js as Server, and deploy to Heroku, and client side using React native (Expo) networking using Axios,
My problem when I use Postman and native Browser to request api, its perfecly working, but when I use axios to request api, show Network Error

```
Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:88:22 in handleError
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:575:10 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This my react native request api

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://myapp.herokuapp.com/member-test', {
      headers:{  
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(res => {
        alert(res)
        const categories = res.data;
        console.log("Sukses");
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        alert(response.message)
      })
  }, []);
```

And my server side

```
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var corsOptions ={    
  origin : true,  
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['Content-Length', 'X-Foo', 'X-Bar'],
  optionsSuccessStatus : 200
}
app.use(cors({corsOptions}));
app.get('/member-test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Api Live');
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I dont know where the problem, I'm stuck for this few days,
I really need help for this problem

Comment: Try to add `origin: '*'` or your allowed origin url

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried origin url, but still not work

Answer (score 0):

You are passing corsOptions as an Object to cors middleware, try to change this line

```
app.use(cors({corsOptions}));
```

In this

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I hope it can be help you.